# Explanation in EL. how is EL working?

Tags: java, el

why is this working?

```
    <td><c:forEach items="${profileForm.cityOptions}" var="city">
                ....Some Code
    </c:forEach></td>
```

and in my `profielForm` been i only have a `getCityOptions()` method  nothing  of `cityOptions` .
its working but i need some explanation.

Comment: This is what is actually publicly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the principle of the EL. It looks for Java bean properties. A bean property is some information available by a public getter, obeying the JavaBeans conventions. It can also be set using a JavaBean setter, obeying the JavaBeans conventions:

```
public Foo getFoo();
public void setFoo(Foo foo);
public boolean isCool();
public void setCool(boolean cool);
```

The EL doesn't care about the fields of your objects. This is private, encapsulated stuff. So `getFoo()` could trigger a complex computation returning a `Foo` instance, or simply return a field named `foo`, `bar` or anything else. The EL doesn't care.

Comment: so in your example i would write `${Foo.something}` ? even though Foo isn't a variable?

Comment: No. You would write `${someObject.foo}` and it would call `getFoo()` on the object stored in the page, request, session or application attribute named "someObject".